# Issue Adding images to UISegmentedControl

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I made a segmented control in my app and I want to show images instead of text.

So, I created UIImage array and then I added this array to segmented control items. These images looks like they are added but showing correctly.

**What i have tried so far**

```
import UIKit

class TestView: UIView {


var segmentedControls : UISegmentedControl = {
    var items : [UIImage] = [UIImage]()
    items=[UIImage(named:"pokeball-1")!,UIImage(named:"pokeball-1")!,UIImage(named:"pokeball-1")!]

    var sc = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
    sc.tintColor = .blue
    sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    return sc
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
    setupConstraints()
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupViews(){
    addSubview(segmentedControls)
}

func setupConstraints(){
    let h = self.frame.height
    let w = self.frame.width
    segmentedControls.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    segmentedControls.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    segmentedControls.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    segmentedControls.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

    }
}
```

**Output of my code**

[image: Output Image]

How can I show these images correctly? Please help me and thanks all of answers.

Comment: Is the screenshot what you get or what you expect ? What do you expect ? The image in items are the same. Is it on purpose ?

Comment: No I dont want to be like this screenshot. I wanted to show "If I compile this code it works like that." But I want to see the image how can I see? Yes I know image items are the same its just sample.

Comment: If I can show these images, how can I set image size?

Comment: Sorry but your question(s) is not clear at all.

Answer (score 1):

Segmented control images are *template* images. If you want to see the actual image, change the image rendering mode to `.alwaysOriginal`.